# Limit of limits of linear combinations of indicator functions

Tags: real-analysis, limits, measure-theory

I have a sequence of functions $0\leq f_1\leq f_2\leq ... \leq f_n \leq ...$, each one defined in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with values in $\mathbb{R}$. I have also that $f_n\uparrow f$.
Every $f_i$ is the limit (almost everywhere) of "step" functions, that is a linear combination of rectangles indicator functions.

Is there a way to prove that also $f$ is the limit of "step" functions?

Comment: ...diagonal sequence?